# Dynamic .htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I updated my site twice since the last year and I have different page names since my first version. Is it possible to create dynamic rules in apache?

for example:

I use to have these pages (example):

- /abc123 (version 1)
- /abc_123 (version 2)
- /abc-123/ (version 3 - current)

I want to create a rule that will redirect abc123 to abc_123 if it exists and abc_123 to abc-123 if it exists.
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in the answer you accepted about "if it exists." So, apparently that was not actually part of your question, why did you ask it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not this?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$ /$1-$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)_([0-9]+)$ /$1-$2 [NC,L]
```

**EDIT:**

or you can use 1 rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(_?)([0-9]+)/?$ /$1-$3 [NC,L]
```

this way it's easy to add characters in the `(_?)` instead of creating the same rule over and over with a little variance.

Answer (score -6):

I found [this example](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3794598.htm):

```
RewriteEngine on
#
# If the requested URL exists as a file with a .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# internally rewrite requested .html URL to .php file
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

You will want to read about the various options and edit it to make it work for your situation.